# Updating every 60 seconds Google Spreadsheet Data into a Discord embed message

Tags: google-sheets, discord.js

My question was if there's any way I could check every 60 seconds if a new row has been created in a `if() else` statement with these outcomes: If so, send that data into a Discord Embed message, if not, just re-check after another 60 seconds have passed by and repeat that over and over again.

I tried to search on Internet already and tried some things, but nothing seems to work or has a clear answer for me, so I wanted to ask here if anyone got a solution for me.

(edit):
if there's a way someone show me how to get Spreadsheet data into Javascript every 60 seconds that would fix my current struggle too!

Comment: Can you describe better what you are trying to do? On Google sheets you have Apps Script that can execute a js function when a sheet is edited, see [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

Comment: @Kessy Basically I wanna get data of a specific string like: "first name" (for example) that checks every 60 seconds if there are any new first names. If so, send that data onto that "first name" string. If not, re-check when the 60 seconds have passed. Hope you get to understand now of what I mean :)

Comment: How are you working with it? Are you using the sheet API to fetch the sheet or Apps Script would be feasible? On apps script, the triggers mentioned on the previous comment can execute apps script functions every X time or when the sheet is edited, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setInterval(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).
Example:

```js
setInterval(function() { //Set an interval
    if (...) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed.setTitle('Data found!');
        ...
    }
}, 60000); //Time in milliseconds
```